# Transforming a sequence of integers into the binary representation of that sequence's strides

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, stride

I have a long array of 32 bit integers which represent a time series, e.g.
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12...]` (though mine is more or less random)

I would like to do **two** things to do this data to prepare it for its Machine Learning Fate™ in Tensorflow.  The **first** thing I would like to do is convert each of these integers to their *bitwise* representation (32 bits): e.g.

```
x= range(100)
bits =(df[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(width,dtype='uint64')) > 0).astype(int)
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
...
```

Endianness isn't particularly important here.  The **second** thing I would like to do is slice this data into n-length steps, in order to create time-series data like (for example) (t-4,t-3,t-2,t-1).  For example, on the above sequence with `n=4` we get
`[[0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], ...`
The excellent solution provided at [Split Python sequence (time series/array) into subsequences with overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852343/split-python-sequence-time-series-array-into-subsequences-with-overlap) provides an efficient solution for this:

```
def subsequences(ts, window):
    shape = (ts.size - window + 1, window)
    strides = ts.strides * 2
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(ts, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

Each of these solutions works individually, but the problem is that I don't know how to *compose* them;  I would like a three-dimensional array that contains the bitwise array of each timestep:

```
[
    [
        [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0],
        [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0],
        [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0],
        [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    ],
    [
        [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0],
        [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0],
        [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0],
        [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    ],
    ...
```

Is there a way to do this that takes advantage of Numpy's vectorized implementations of these operations?  Clearly running the bitwise expansion before the stride is faster, but the problem is that I am unsure of the correct shape and stride to pass to `stride_tricks.as_strided`.  It's also possible this is a solved problem in either Tensorflow or Numpy.

Comment: This should solve your second part of sliding windows - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413582/selecting-multiple-slices-from-a-numpy-array-at-once, specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413801/.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked great.

Comment: So can we close this as a dup of the linked one?

Comment: I think so!  It seems like they are asking the same question as this one, but the answer that they accepted doesn't seem to solve this problem.