# Applying rolling function with second data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Let's take two datasets:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7])

check_df = pd.DataFrame([3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1])
```

I want to do the following thing:

1. If any of numbers `df[0:3]` is greater than `check_df[0]`, then we return 1 and 0 otherwise
2. If any of numbers `df[1:4]` is greater than `check_df[1]` then we return 1 and 0 otherwise
3. And so on...

It can be done, by `rolling` function and custom function:

```
def custom_fun(x: pd.DataFrame):
    return (x > float(check_df.iloc[0])).any()
```

And then by combining this with `apply` function:

```
df.rolling(3, min_periods = 3).apply(custom_fun).shift(-2)
```

The main problem in my solution, is that I always compare with `check_df[0]`, whereas in i-th rolling window, I should compare with `check_df[i]`, but I have no idea how it can be specified in the rolling function. Could you please give me a hand in this problem?

Comment: IIUC, this was already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73065778/compare-two-pandas-dataframes-in-the-most-efficient-way/73066990#73066990. You can just compare `check_df[i]` with the maximum of the rolling window of `df[i:i+3]`

Comment: Do you need processing only one column?

Comment: Yes only one ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use the first index of `x`, for example, with [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html):

```
def custom_fun(x: pd.DataFrame):
    return (x > float(check_df.iloc[x.first_valid_index()])).any()


res = df.rolling(3, min_periods=3).apply(custom_fun).shift(-2)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
     0
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  0.0
3  1.0
4  1.0
5  0.0
6  1.0
7  NaN
8  NaN
```

As an alternative, use:

```
def custom_fun(x: pd.DataFrame):
    return (x > float(check_df.iloc[x.index[0]])).any()
```